# Cassandra CLI: RowKey with RandomPartitioner = Show Key in Cleartext?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

using Cassandra CLI gives me the following output:

```
RowKey: 31307c32333239
=> (super_column=3f18d800-fed5-17cf-b91a-0016e6df0376,
     (column=date, value=1312289229287, timestamp=1312289229647000)
```

I am using `RandomPartitioner`. Is it somehow possible to get the RowKey (from CLI) in Cleartext? Ideally in the CLI but if there is a Helper Class to convert it back into a String, this would also be ok.

I know the key is somehow hashed. If the key can not be "retrieved" (what I have to assume), Is there are helper Class exposed in Cassandra, that I can use to generate the Key based on my original String to compare them?

My Problem: I have stored Records in Cassandra, but using the Key like `"user1|order1"` I am not able to retrieve the records. Cassandra does not find any records. I assume that somehow my keys are wrong and I need to compare them and find out whtere the problem is...

Thanks very much !! Jens

Comment: post the code you are using to read and write to cassandra, and perhaps we can tell you why your reads are failing

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly relevant: [Cassandra cli: Convert hex values into a human-readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662940/cassandra-cli-returning-weird-code)

The only difference is that in Cassandra 0.8, there is now a "key_validation_class" attribute per column family, and it defaults to BytesType.  When the CLI sees that it's BytesType, it represents the key in hex.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is treating your RowKey as hex bytes: `31 30 7c 32 33 32 39` in hex is 
`10|2329` in ASCII, which I guess is your key.

If you want to see your plaintext keys in the CLI, then you need to give the command `assume MyColumnFamily keys as ascii;` which will make the CLI automatically translate between ASCII and hex for you in the row keys.

Or, when you create the column family, use `create column family MyColumnFamily with key_validation_class = AsciiType;` which will set the preference permanently.

The hashing occurs at a lower level and doesn't affect your problem.